# Trying to understand relative homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm reading about relative homology group but I'm having hard time in understanding this concept.

So I was trying to find $H_1(D^n,S^{n-1})$, but I'm unable to solve this problem. Can someone give some idea for $n=1$ (Then I'll try to generalize it)?

**Added** By using long exact sequence as suggested in comment I get $H_n(D_n,S^{n-1})$ is isomorphic to $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$.How to proceed further?

Comment: A possible approach: You should start with the definition of the relative chain complex. Then go on with the long exact sequence of homology.

Comment: @QuangHoang but that does not work for $n=1$,I think?

Comment: OP, maybe you want to try to clarify what is exactly that you don't understand?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi I think I understand the definition of Relative homology group but still I'm not getting a way to compute it.Can you tell about my particularexample which I'm trying?

Comment: You can use the long exact sequence of the pair, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_homology#Properties

Comment: @Pedro but this does not work for $n=1$,right?

Answer (score 2):

The long exact sequence of the pair (plus the fact $H_1(D^1) = 0$) gives us the exactness of

$0 \to H_1(D^1, S^0) \to H_0(S^0) \to H_0(D^1) \to H_0(D^1, S^0) \to 0$

Hence $H_1(D^1, S^0)$ is just the kernel of the map $H_0(S^0) \to H_0(D^1)$. Recall that (assuming integer coefficients) $H_0(S^0) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_0(D^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. The application $H_0(S^0) \to H_0(D^1)$ is induced by the inclusion $S^0 \hookrightarrow D^1$. Hence in terms of generators it is the application $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto x + y$. Hence its kernel is $\cong \mathbb{Z}$, and thus we have established $H_1(D^1, S^0) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: (+1),Can you please add for general  $n$ too?Thank you!

Comment: The ideas are the same... what are you having trouble with?

Comment: By using long exact sequence I got $H_n(D^n,S^{n-1})$ is isomorphic to  $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$ then how to proceed?Do we need to use some induction argument?

Comment: You can use, for example, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence to show $H_{n-1}(S^{n - 1}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. This is a well-known calculation which you can find in any algebraic topology textbook

Comment: Or the fact that, since $(D^n, S^{n - 1})$ is a good pair, $H_n(D^n, S^{n - 1}) \cong \widetilde{H}_n(D^n / S^{n-1}) \cong \widetilde{H}_n(S^n)$ and so inductively calculate this.